# Code to copy from one column to another based on values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need VBA code so that the entries from F4, G4, H4 and I4 downwards will be searched and any entries starting with "07" will be copied over into the same row on column N.  Also if any of the entries have been duplicated over two or more columns, then N will only show one instance of that number.  It's for the purpose of putting mobile numbers into one column.

I imagine it involves IF code but I really don't know where to start and would appreciate the help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I need a lot of things too, you know.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what you have and what you want your output to be. Also its better to add what you have tried.

Comment: I need a lot of things too, mate.

Comment: Thanks, will remember that for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a formula in column N

```
=IF(LEFT(F:F,2)="07",F:F,IF(LEFT(G:G,2)="07",G:G,IF(LEFT(H:H,2)="07",H:H,IF(LEFT(I:I,2)="07",I:I,"-"))))
```

[image]